# No such file or directory in ftplib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

So, I'm trying to write a synchronization program for files on my tablet and other computers. Unfortunately, I'm only fairly familiar with python and ftplib. Here's the code:

```
#DOWNLOADING
for file in rContents:
    if rIsFolder(ftp, file):
        rFolders.append(file)
        continue
    if file in contents:
        print "%s already uploaded." % file
    else:
        try:
            print ftp.pwd()
            print "Downloading %s..." % file
            with open(file, 'rb') as f:        
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % file, f.write)
            print "    ...done."
        except:
            print "Failed download of %s." % file
```

I'm especially concerned with these two lines:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:        
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % file, f.write)
```

On the line "with open..." I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FolderSync.py", line 145, in <module>
    sync(ftp, folder, tabFolder)
  File "FolderSync.py", line 67, in sync
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:        
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'u.txt'
```

I'm actually using ftp.nlst() to get these file names, so 'u.txt' is absolutely there, but on the ftp side. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a different function to open this file remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve file, you need to open file with write mode (`wb`).

Replace following line:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
```

with:

```
with open(file, 'wb') as f:
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Can you help me with this?

    OpenedFile = open(file, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR' + file, openedFile)

Those are the lines I'm using to upload, but they're not working either.

Edit: formatting not working here. I'll put it in as an edit.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the help.

My problem with the upload lines was that I was missing a space. Silly me.